# unstow directory causes warning

Tags: macos, shell, gnu, symlink

When I run:

`stow -D folderName`

I get:

```
WARNING! unstowing folderName would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .DS_Store
All operations aborted.
```

How can I solve? I find [this tip](https://github.com/unixorn/zsh-quickstart-kit/issues/7) but I didn't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try executing this command before `stow`:

```
find folderName -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm -f {} \;
```

That will remove any `.DS_Store` files in **folderName**, which seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you know why I don't see .DS_Store files even if I see hidden files?

Comment: @vila: You're welcome! The only way to really see `.DS_Store` files natively from 10.14 up is to use the `-a` option with `ls` in Terminal (eg. `ls -a`).